# Adding attributes in a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows

```
data = [
 {
  "tag":"A",
  "list":[
   {
    "list_tag":1
   },
   {
    "list_tag":2
   }
   ]
 },
 {
  "tag":"B",
 "list":[
   {
    "list_tag":3
   },
   {
    "list_tag":4
   }
   ]
 },
 {
  "tag":"C",
 "list":[
   {
    "list_tag":5
   },
   {
    "list_tag":6
   }
   ]
 }
];
```

I have a method which get tag value as argument and then for that particular tag I need to make a new array  three new attributes. Suppose if value of tag coming as method argument is "A". My final array will look as follows:

```
finalArray = [
 {
  "types":"list_tag",
  "label":"1",
  "Value":"1"
 },
 {
  "types":"list_tag",
  "label":"2",
  "Value":"2"
 }
 ]
```

types will always be "tag" and label and value will list_tag value from data array. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried? [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object with `"tag":"A"` from `data` array and loop through its `list` property and create new objects. Seems straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to get only those items that match the input tag.

We then call [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) on the `filtered` array to create the desired result.

Finally we must call [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Flat) to flatten the result.

```js
const data = [ { "tag":"A", "list":[ { "list_tag":1 }, { "list_tag":2 } ] }, { "tag":"B", "list":[ { "list_tag":3 }, { "list_tag":4 } ] }, { "tag":"C", "list":[ { "list_tag":5 }, { "list_tag":6 } ] } ]; 

function getResult(input, tagValue) {
    const filtered = input.filter(({ tag} ) => tag === tagValue);
    return filtered.map(({ tag, list }) => { 
        return list.map(({ list_tag }) => { 
            return { types: 'list_tag', label: list_tag, Value: list_tag };
        })
    }).flat();
}

const result = getResult(data, 'A');
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can also use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the desired output, this is probably more compact.

```js
const data = [ { "tag":"A", "list":[ { "list_tag":1 }, { "list_tag":2 } ] }, { "tag":"B", "list":[ { "list_tag":3 }, { "list_tag":4 } ] }, { "tag":"C", "list":[ { "list_tag":5 }, { "list_tag":6 } ] } ]; 

function getResult(input, tagValue) {
    return input.reduce((acc, { tag, list }) => { 
        if (tag === tagValue) {
            acc.push(...list.map(el => ({ types: 'list_tag', label: el.list_tag, Value: el.list_tag })))
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

const result = getResult(data, 'A');
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```